# How to store values of multiple lists in nested dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, zip

I've looked at the documentation of how to convert two lists into a dictionary but it doesn't seem to apply here. So a simple zip function won't do the trick here. I've tried a lot of different things which all lead to messy headache code lines. I've outlined the result I'm looking for below.

```
list_01 = ['name_01', 'name_02', 'name_03']
list_02 = ['size_01', 'size_02', 'size_03']
list_03 = ['path_01', 'path_02', 'path_03']
list_04 = ['count_01', 'count_02', 'count_03']

data = {}
```

**Result I'm looking for:**

```
{'data': {'name_01': {
                    'name':'name_01',
                    'size':'size_01',
                    'path':'path_01',
                    'count':'count_01'},
        'name_02': {
                    'name':'name_02',
                    'size':'size_02',
                    'path':'path_02',
                    'count':'count_02'}
        'name_03': {
                    'name':'name_03',
                    'size':'size_03',
                    'path':'path_03',
                    'count':'count_03'}}}
```

A side question would be why I often see list brackets in dicts when working json? A list in this example wouldn't make sense for me (source: [link](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)) Is it a good choice to use lists instead of dicts in dicts?

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "from": "Nebraska",
            "name": "Scott",
            "website": "stackabuse.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The brackets are for a list/array of people.  Each person in the list is a dictionary.  There is only one person in this particular list/array of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['data'] = {name:{'name': name, 'size': size, 'path': path, 'count': count} 
    for name, size, path, count in zip(list_01, list_02, list_03, list_04)}
```

result of `pprint.pprint(data)`

```
{'data': {'name_01': {'count': 'count_01',
                      'name': 'name_01',
                      'path': 'path_01',
                      'size': 'size_01'},
          'name_02': {'count': 'count_02',
                      'name': 'name_02',
                      'path': 'path_02',
                      'size': 'size_02'},
          'name_03': {'count': 'count_03',
                      'name': 'name_03',
                      'path': 'path_03',
                      'size': 'size_03'}}}
```

Comment: This community is simply wonderful. Thanks for that fast answer! Any Idea how to write it without list comprehension?

Comment: @BenjaminK Without the dict comprehension: `data['data'] = {};for name, size, path, count in zip(list_01, list_02, list_03, list_04):data['data'][name] = {'name': name, 'size': size, 'path': path, 'count': count}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension combined with `zip` to construct your dictionary while iterating over the zipped lists.

```
data = {
    name: {
        'name': name,
        'size': size,
        'path': path,
        'count': count,
    } for name, size, path, count in 
    zip(list_01, list_02, list_03, list_04)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data["data"]=[]
data["data"].append({"itemlist0":itemlist0})
....
```